# Regex to find out a substring that starts with a space and ends with a substring

Tags: javascript, regex

I am currently new to Regex, can someone help me with it?
So the text that I have is the following:

```
yolo _time<=$info_max_time$ (index=* OR index=_*) $threat_match_value$ [search _time=2022-09-26T11:17:12.000-07:00 index=threat_activity   | head 1 | `makemv(orig_sourcetype)` | rename orig_sourcetype as sourcetype | mvexpand sourcetype | return 100 sourcetype]
```

I want a regex that finds out the string for example, given that it starts with a space and match ends when it gets the provided substring

```
_time<=$info_max_time$
```

So I have $info_max_time$, I want to search for the string which starts with a space and ends with $info_max_time$. Now in between it can have any characters, _ , = or <= or >="

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Use `\s\S+?\$info_max_time\$`. Demo: https://regex101.com/r/VqmNAc/1

Comment: @Nick output: _time<=$info_max_time$ with that regex. The solution above worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use:

```
\s\S+?\$info_max_time\$
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VqmNAc/1)**.

**Details:**

- `\s` - A whitespace character.
- `\S+?` - One or more non-whitespace characters (non-greedy quantifier).
- `\$info_max_time\$` - Match "$info_max_time$" literally.

Note that `\s` will match any whitespace characters (e.g., tab, EOL, etc.). If you're only interested in the ASCII space (AKA `%20`), you may use the following instead:

```
[ ][^ ]+?\$info_max_time\$
```